# Invite users to a Google Apps domain

Tags: g-suite, user-accounts

I have a google apps domain which is associated with the google sites feature, google email and so on. How do you invite users to your google apps? According to the google apps help, there should be an "Invite Users" link on the dashboard. But since there's no such link, can someone tell me how to do it?

Note: I do not want to create new google accounts, I want to invite existing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for our Google Apps for Education account, we cannot invite members outside of our domain.  We can only create new accounts.  The Google Apps accounts are separate from regular Google accounts.

I have seen documentation that says this is changing (as of a year ago for some!), but for us, the account space is still completely separate.

Comment: Wow, that kind of sucks.. But thanks for your answer!